# Trigger to update field on Account, on related opportunities, which is a custom lookup from Account to Opportunity

Tags: trigger

I have the below trigger to update count of Opportunities not equal to Stagename closed on the account page field `Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c`

The below trigger is working for Deletes,inserts and if from opportunities the account association is removed.

But for testing purpose, if I change a opportunity from `'9-Closed'` to any other `Open` value, the count of project number is not getting updated

Can you please give me some pointers regarding this

```
trigger CountProjectonAccounts on Opportunity (after insert, after delete,after undelete,after update) {


    Set<Id> aId = new Set<Id>();

if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        aId.add(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
    }
    List<Account> acc = [select id,Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c from Account where Id in:aId];
    List<Opportunity> con = [select id from Opportunity where StageName!='9- Lost' and Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c in :aId];

    for(Account a : acc){
        a.Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c=con.size();

    }update acc;
}

if(Trigger.isDelete){
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.old){
        aId.add(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
    }
    List<Account> acc = [select id,Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c from Account where Id in:aId];
    List<Opportunity> con = [select id from Opportunity where StageName!='9- Lost' and Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c in :aId];

    for(Account a : acc){
        a.Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c=con.size();

    }update acc;
}

if(Trigger.isUpdate){
   Set<Id> OldAId = new Set<Id>(); 
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
    if(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c)
        aId.add(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
        OldAId.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);

    }
    if(!aId.isEmpty()){
    //for new Accounts
    List<Account> acc = [select id,Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c from Account where Id in:aId];
    //For New Account Contacts
    List<Opportunity> con = [select id from Opportunity where StageName!='9- Lost' and Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c in :aId];

    /*
    This is For Old Contacts Count
                          */

    //for Old Accounts
    List<Account> Oldacc = [select id,Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c from Account where Id in:OldAId];

    //For Old Account Contacts
    List<Opportunity> OldCon = [select id from Opportunity where StageName!='9- Lost' and Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c in :OldAId];

    //For New Accounts
    for(Account a : acc){
        a.Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c=con.size();


    }update acc;

    //For Old Accounts
    for(Account a : Oldacc){
        a.Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c=OldCon.size();

    }update Oldacc;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just use [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), then you don't need any of your own `Apex`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Fields on Opportunity can be RSF'd to Account; why DLRS?

Comment: @crop1645 didn't think about if it was m/d, figured they would have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a logic problem in addition to your what you state. The logic problem is that you are not associating the account being updated with the collection of opportunities. That will be problematic when you have more than one account in the collection.

I changed your code to be cleaner (less repetition) to adjust your logic problem and to solve your stated issue (you have to check if the stage changed, not only if the portfolio changed)

```
trigger CountProjectonAccounts on Opportunity (after insert, after delete,after undelete,after update) {


    Set<Id> aId = new Set<Id>();
    List<Opportunity> oppsToIterate;

    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isUndelete) {
        oppsToIterate = trigger.new;
    } else if(Trigger.isDelete){
        oppsToIterate = trigger.old;  
    }

    for(Opportunity opp : oppsToIterate){
        if (! trigger.isUpdate) {
            aId.add(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
        } else if (opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c ||
                   opp.StageName != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).StageName) {
            aId.add(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
            aId.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
        }

    }

    //Check the name `Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolios__r` to make sure it matches your actual relationship name
    List<Account> acc = [select id,Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c, (Select Id from Opportunities where StageName!='9-Lost') from Account where Id in:aId];

    for(Account a : acc){
        a.Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c = a.Opportunities.size();

    }
    update acc;

}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thank you very much for your feedback..But when i run the trigger mentioned by you i got the below error "Didn't understand relationship 'Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolios__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."                                         Line:25

Comment: Look at my comment above that line. I don't know what you've named your relationship. To see the actual name, go to the `Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c` field on the `Opportunity` object,  and see the "Child Relationship Name" field. Then simply put that name in the proper places in the code.

Comment: @sebastian..Thanks.. Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c is a field on the Account Page. I have put the correct relationship name Opportunities__r and the code compiles perfectly.. But it counts all opportunities and doesn't take Stagename in consideration..

Comment: Ooops. I should've seen that. Apologies. I've updated my code. Please check that the SELECT statement in your code looks exactly like mine. The "where" clause for `opportunities` must be within the subquery

Comment: And, if this helps you, don't hesitate to mark the question as accepted so others can see this exchange and benefit from the answer

Comment: @sebastian..it doesnt work...please find my updated code as suggested by you

Comment: Sam, please update your orginal post.... And I found the error. Use `Opportunities`, not `Opportunities__r`

Comment: @Sebastian..Done..Still it doesnt work..

Comment: Sam. You are giving me no errors, no info. I can't very well help you that way

Comment: @Sebastian..The Trigger Compiles with No error. the  a.Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c at Account Page, now Counts the related Opportunity irrespective of the Stage!='9-Closed'. Previously my initial trigger was able to count Related Opportunities associated that were not Closed. But when the status of Staged change from CLosed to Open, it was not able to Count.  With the changes suggested that I have put in the trigger, now it just counts count of related Opportunities irrespective of Stage. Please let me know, if I was able to explain the scenario. Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

trigger CountProjectonAccounts on Opportunity (after insert, after delete,after undelete,after update) {

```
Set<Id> aId = new Set<Id>();
List<Opportunity> oppsToIterate;

if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isUndelete) {
    oppsToIterate = trigger.new;
} else if(Trigger.isDelete){
    oppsToIterate = trigger.old;  
}

for(Opportunity opp : oppsToIterate){
    if (! trigger.isUpdate) {
        aId.add(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
    } else if (opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c ||
               opp.StageName != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).StageName) {
        aId.add(opp.Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
        aId.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolio__c);
    }

}

//Check the name `Oppor_Existing_Hotel_Plot_Portfolios__r` to make sure it matches your actual relationship name
List<Account> acc = [select id,Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c, (Select Id from Opportunities where StageName!='9-Lost') from Account where Id in:aId];

for(Account a : acc){
    a.Count_Of_Projects_Not_Lost__c = a.Opportunities.size();

}
update acc;
```

}